# Get value from service in ngOnInit in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I have a service which essentially contains a single value.  I'm trying to use this value in a deeply nested component.  The reason I'm using a service is because the value can be changed via a route parameter elsewhere in the application.  The component which will consume the service is outside of the `routeroutlet`, hence the need to store the route parameter in this service.

The service is like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class RouteParamService {

    private contentId = new Subject<number>();
    contentId$ = this.contentId.asObservable();

    setCurrentContentId(id: number) {
        this.contentId.next(id);
    }

}
```

I'm calling `setCurrentContentId` from a component using the value from the route parameter, like this (this snippet has been truncated as it's quite a large component):

```
@Routes([
    { path:'/',    component: ContentDashboardComponent },
    { path:'/:id', component: ContentEditComponent }
])
export class ContentComponent {

    constructor( 
        private router:Router, 
        private routeSerializer:RouterUrlSerializer, 
        private location:Location, 
        private routeParamService:RouteParamService
    ) {
        router.changes.first().subscribe(() => {
            let urlTree = this.routeSerializer.parse(location.path());
            let urlSegment = urlTree.children(urlTree.children(urlTree.root)[0])[0];
            if(urlSegment != undefined){
                this.routeParamService.setCurrentContentId(urlSegment.segment);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

All good so far.  If I console.log the value passed to `setCurrentContentId` it appears to be correct and called at the right times.

What I need to do now though is use this value from the service in the `ngOnInit` method on a completely different component elsewhere in the app.  Here's a truncated version of what's in this component:

```
export class ContentTreeComponent implements OnInit {

    _currentNodeId: number;

    constructor(
        private _contentService: ContentService,
        private _router: Router,
        private _currSegment: RouteSegment,
        private _queryStringService: RouteParamService
    ) { 
        _queryStringService.contentId$.subscribe(contentId => {
            console.log('contentId = ' + contentId); // This logs the right thing!
            this._currentNodeId = contentId;
        });
    }

    errorMessage: string;

    @Input('startNodeId')
    private _startNodeId: number;

    contentNodes: ContentNode[];

    ngOnInit() { 
        this.getContentNodes();
        console.log('currentNodeId = ' + this._currentNodeId); // This always logs 'undefined'
    }
}
```

The value is correctly received from the service in the constructor, as per the code comment above.  However, when I try to use this value in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle method, it's always `undefined`.

I'm guessing this is because the subscription in the constructor is asynchronous?

How do I get the value from the service in `ngOnInit`?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Do I even need an `observable` for this, or am I over-complicating things?  Essentially I just want to have a value from a route parameter available throughout my app.  It's only ever going to be set on page load, not dynamically updated.

**EDIT:**

I've tried moving the code from the constructor to ngOnInit but it still results in an undefined value:

```
constructor(
    private _contentService: ContentService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _currSegment: RouteSegment,
    private _queryStringService: RouteParamService
) { }

ngOnInit() { 
    let _currentNodeId: number;
    this.getContentNodes();
    this._queryStringService.contentId$.subscribe(contentId => {
        console.log('contentId = ' + contentId); // This outputs correctly
        _currentNodeId = contentId;
    });
    console.log('currentNodeId = ' + _currentNodeId); // This is always undefined
}
```

Comment: Why not put the constructor code in the onInit()?

Comment: I've tried that and updated the question - it still won't set the variable to anything other than `undefined`.

Comment: Your console.log should be in the callback. The callback is called asynchronously

Comment: why you think `routeParamService.setCurrentContentId` occurs before `queryStringService.contentId$.subscribe`?

Comment: I don't know which is called first, so perhaps that's the problem.